# AWS EMR Hive: Not yet supported place for UDAF 'COUNT'

Tags: amazon-web-services, hive, hiveql, amazon-emr

I have a pretty complicated query I am trying to convert over to use with Hive.

Specifically, I am running it as a Hive "step" in an AWS EMR cluster.

I have tried to clean up the query a bit for the post and just leave essence of the thing.

The full error message is:

```
FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10128]: Line XX:XX Not yet supported place for UDAF 'COUNT'
```

The line number is pointing to the `COUNT` at the bottom of the select statement:

```
    INSERT INTO db.new_table (
        new_column1,
        new_column2,
        new_column3,
        ... ,
        new_column20
    ) 
    SELECT MD5(COALESCE(TBL1.col1," ")||"_"||COALESCE(new_column5," ")||"_"||...) AS 
        new_col1,
        TBL1.col2,
        TBL1.col3,
        TBL1.col3 AS new_column3,
        TBL1.col4,
        CASE
            WHEN TBL1.col5 = …
            ELSE “some value”
        END AS new_column5,
        TBL1.col6,
        TBL1.col7,
        TBL1.col8,
        CASE
            WHEN TBL1.col9 = …
            ELSE "some value"
        END AS new_column9,
        CASE 
            WHEN TBL1.col10 = …
            ELSE "value"
        END AS new_column10,
        TBL1.col11,
        "value" AS new_column12,
        TBL2.col1,
        TBL2.col2,
        from_unixtime(…) AS new_column13,
        CAST(…) AS new_column14,
        CAST(…) AS new_column15,
        CAST(…) AS new_column16,
        COUNT(DISTINCT TBL1.col17) AS new_column17
    FROM db.table1 TBL1
    LEFT JOIN 
        db.table2 TBL2
            ON TBL1.col311 = TBL2.col311
    WHERE TBL1.col14 BETWEEN "low" AND "high"
        AND TBL1.col44 = "Y"
        AND TBL1.col55 = "N"
    GROUP BY 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20;
```

If I have left out too much, please let me know.

Thanks for your help!

**Updates**

It turns out, I did in fact leave out way too much info. Sorry for those who have already tried to help...

I made the updates above.

Removing the 20th group by column, eg:

```
GROUP BY 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19;
```

Produced: `Expression not in GROUP BY key '' ''`

**LATEST**

Removing the 20th group by column and adding the first one, eg:

```
GROUP BY 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19;
```

Produced:

```
Line XX:XX Invalid table alias or column reference 'new_column5':(possible column
 names are: TBL1.col1, TBL1.col2, (looks like all columns of TBL1), 
TBL2.col1, TBL2.col2, TBL2.col311)
```

Line # is referring the line with the SELECT statement. Just those three columns from TBL2 are listed in the error output.

The error seems to be pointing to `COALESCE(new_column5)`. Note that I have a `CASE` statement within the TBL 1 select which I am running with `AS new_column5`.

Comment: group by does not conform with select columns IMHO. you have 20 columns in total. 20th is count

Comment: Thanks for the tip, but removing the 20th column changes the error message to 
`FAILED: SemanticException [Error 10025]: Line 23:181 Expression not in GROUP BY key '' ''`

Comment: add 1st column  also

Comment: Thank you again for your help on this. I think i did leave out a bit too much info. I tested your suggestion and did get a new error message. I updated the question with the details of that change and included the full query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are addressing calculated column name `new_column5` at the same subquery level where it is being calculated. This is not possible in Hive. Replace it with calculation itself or use upper level subquery.

This:

```
 MD5(COALESCE(TBL1.col1," ")||"_"||COALESCE(CASE WHEN TBL1.col5 = … ELSE “some value” END," ")||"_"||...) AS new_col1,
```

Instead of this:

```
 MD5(COALESCE(TBL1.col1," ")||"_"||COALESCE(new_column5," ")||"_"||...) AS 
        new_col1,
```